# Octave - Why $0.6-0.2-0.2-0.2 \neq 0$, but $0.4-0.2-0.2 = 0$?

Tags: numerical-methods, octave

I am newbie about this subject. I have no idea, why:

> $$\text{octave}: 0.6 - 0.2 - 0.2 - 0.2$$
>   $$\text{ans}=   -5.55111512312578\times 10^{-17}$$

It should be $0$.  However in case:

> $$\text{octave}: 0.4 - 0.2 - 0.2$$
>   $$\text{ans}= 0$$

We got correct result. I don't see a point. Can you explain me it, please ?

Comment: Note that $0.6 = 3/5$ is not exactly represented by any terminating binary number.  Therefore rounding errors can and will enter into the evaluation of operations involving such numbers.

Comment: Generally, floating point arithmetic is approximation in computers. You get errors like this all the time.

Comment: That is also why you generally should be very careful when comparing floating point numbers with `==` or `!=`. Testing with `>=` or `<` or similar is still OK, most of the time.

Comment: You get the same result with other languages such as JavaScript too.

Answer (score 3):

None of those numbers
can be represented exactly
in double precision floating point.

Because of the nature
of the representation,
0.4 has exactly the same
fractional part as 0.2 -
only the binary exponent
is one larger.
Therefore,
0.4-0.2 is computed to give
0.2.

However,
0.6 has a different fractional part
which is such that
when 0.6-0.4 is computed
it differs by 1 in the last bit
by the representation of 0.2.

Check the actual bits
making up the numbers
and you will see what happens.

Comment: I still don't understand.  $$0.2 = 00111110010011001100110011001101 = 2^{-3} \cdot  1.600000023841858 $$  $$0.4 = 00111110110011001100110011001101 = 2^{-2} \cdot  1.600000023841858$$ $$0.6  = 00111111000110011001100110011010 =2^{-1}\cdot  1.2000000476837158 $$  Yes, I can see that they aren't exact results. However - Why $0.4 - 0.2 - 0.2 =0$ and $0.6 - 0.2 - 0.2 - 0.2 - 0.2 \neq 0$   ?